# CodeIgniter: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, connection

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: libraries/Session/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 102

I am newbie for CI, went i start Db to my Website i get this error and i don't know how to reslove.

Can you resolve this error, please?

application/config/database.php

```
    $active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;
    require_once('mainconfig.php');
 $db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => $config['mysql_host'],
        'username' => $config['mysql_username'],
        'password' => $config['mysql_password'],
        'database' => $config['mysql_database'],
        'dbdriver' => $config['mysql_driver'],
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => $config['mysql_charset'],
        'dbcollat' => $config['mysql_dbcollat'],
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

application/config/mainconfig.php

```
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 $config['mysql_host'] = 'localhost';
 $config['mysql_username'] = 'xxxcc';
 $config['mysql_password'] = 'xxxcc';
 $config['mysql_database'] = 'xxccv';
 $config['mysql_driver'] = 'mysqli';
 $config['mysql_charset'] = 'utf8';
 $config['mysql_dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
 $config['base_js'] = 'assets/js';
 $config['base_css'] = 'assets/css';
 $config['base_plugins'] = 'assets/plugins';
 $config['base_images'] = 'assets/images';
 $config['base_fonts'] = 'assets/font-awesome';
 $config['other_base'] = 'assets/fonts';
 $config['email_author'] = 'admin@localhost';
 $config['limit'] = 7;
```

Comment: check database connection in application/config/database.php

Answer (score 0):

if u use codeigniter 3 then please use latest version of php. Once i got these errors but then i update my php then it works after successfully setup codeigniter on my project.

And please follow in your application/config/database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'db_bdtimes', // your database name
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: I'm Using php 5.5 and i have to Update to 5.6?

Comment: Lets give a try ! But have u set up a database for your project ?

Comment: I try it but its fail.

Comment: set your database name here
 'database' => 'db_bdtimes', // your database name

Comment: No, I set the database in mainconfig.php

Comment: change it to mysql $config['mysql_driver'] = 'mysqli';  // set mysql in place of mysqli

Comment: I use mysqli to mysql driver,  i set up PHP 7 and that configuration, the error   change to Blank page

Answer (score 0):

Just change and it will work for sure

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';

to

$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';